# Select all after specific word javascript regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I have problem with this string AlertID=234423. I want select only 234423 how i can do that? I try something like that :

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

      var $str = "AlertID=234423"

      alert($($str).match("(?<=D=).*"));
      alert($str);

});
```

What i do wrong?

Ok I use this and now is ok:
`$forma.match(/ID=(\d+)/)[1]`
thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 2):

Use `String#split`:

```
var r = AlertID=234423'.split('=')[1];
//=> 234423
```

Or using `String#substring`:

```
var s = 'AlertID=234423';
var r = s.substring(s.indexOf('=')+1);
//=> 234423
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have look behind in javascript

```
 alert($str.match(/ID=(\d+)/)[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string is always in the same pattern you can just delete `'AlertID='`:

```
var str = "AlertID=234423";

str  = str.replace('AlertID=', '');
alert(str);
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BT66D/1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this...

```
var str = "AlertID=234423";
var val = str.substring(str.indexOf("=") + 1);
//val = 234423
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6yEE8/)